# Difficulty in coding research papers

Tags: deep-learning, research

I understood how Yolov1 works but finding difficulty in coding it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There's always [Papers With Code](https://paperswithcode.com/method/yolov1)

(Papers With Code is a web site which shows code for published papers).

If you are specifically looking for YOLO v1, then Kaggle has a notebook and a link to a tutorial:

[Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/vexxingbanana/yolov1-from-scratch-pytorch)

[YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9_XyCGr-MI)

Comment: But won't it be just seeing the code and typing it?

Comment: Seeing the code, typing it and understanding why it does what it does is far from the worst way to explore a model. But I also linked to a tutorial.